# How to migrate PHP Code between versions 5 - 7 without rewriting or reviewing all the code

Tags: php, php-7

I'm looking at update codebase I'm working with from PHP5 to PHP7 when PHP7 reaches full release (largely due to the fact the speed gains and the ?? operator could really help our site).

As there are deprecated functions, and some things that are altered between the versions, I'm considering using filemtime on php files before including them to see if I should include functions that will modify php7's behavior to act a bit more like php5 in regards to those files. Although this will work on the existing server, I know various copy methods (some down the pipeline that it will be hard to control) will likely change the modified date as files are copied.

Is there a method for determining which php version a file is written with or compatible with and interpreting them appropriately, or is this hacky and risky solution really my best bet?

Comment: Still looking at hacky solution... but I realized that if instead of just checking if file was modified before a static date of when I push an update, I can at least mitigate it slightly by using a variable date... specifically the date of the file the version-checker is in, and make sure that I successfully push the last php5 update before I push it, then push it by itself, and then push php7 updates after. This still doesn't necessarily help if all the source-code is copied wholesale into a new location at once, but it does help mitigate some issues. Still would like better solutions though.

Comment: I see my question was put on hold for being too opinion based. I've altered my question to hopefully be less so. Any suggestions further?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On solution I see was inspired while hunting for solutions here: [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/run-multiple-versions-php-one-server/)

In short...

1. create two different localhost servers
2. set each localhost to link to a different version of php
3. write code afterwards that pulls from the old code as if it were pulling from a different server.
4. steadily migrate files from old to new version of php after initial migration.

As a result, instead of having to migrate the entire codebase, it can be migrated a chunk at a time, without having to do all-or-nothing all-at-once. It also should be more durable than the filemtime solution. The downside is that it makes it harder to immediately integrate old code into new code.

Still interested in better solutions, but at least it's *a* solution.

Comment: Additional note: 
Since researching this, I've migrated several codebases from 5 to 7. Out of all of them, I've only had one that had any difficulties moving over, and that one was made possible by a mass search&replace of shorttags and a few other things. Migrating from 5 to 7 isn't perfect, it will be time consuming if there's problems, but problems are surprisingly uncommon for a full version jump, and I've been able to run multiple "PHP5 only" solutions on PHP7 with only improvement as a result.

Comment: How to create 2 localhost servers in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I've only pulled that particular trick on a windows machine useing portable app servers. That said, hypothetically, might be possible to use wine to install a second web server, though there's probably a more elegant way to do it in linux, maybe install from source in two different locations?